# converting bytes stream to json using python

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers, mqtt

I'm working on an application that sends me protobuf messages in byte format. the structure of the .proto file is as follows:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package api;

message RXInfoSimplified {
    string ID = 1;
    int32 RSSI = 2;
    float SNR = 3;
}

message DeviceUplink {
    string DevEUI = 1;
    int64 ApplicationID = 2;
    string MsgType = 3;
    int64 Timestamp = 4;
    string GatewayID = 5;
    int32 RSSI = 6;
    float SNR = 7;
    float Frequency = 8;
    int32 DataRate = 9;
    bool ADR = 10;
    string Class = 11;
    uint32 FCnt = 12;
    int32 FPort = 13;
    bool Confirm = 14;
    bytes Data = 15;
    repeated RXInfoSimplified Gateways = 16;
}
```

I have to recover these messages in json format or in dict. I tried to use the python pickle and marshal modules, but it doesn't work. I would like to know if there are other python modules or packages that can help me solve this problem.
I'm using mqtt to receive payload message from server.
My callback function:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.payload)
    print(m)
```

The bytes stream i'm got:

```
b'\n\x108cf9572000023509\x10\x03\x1a\x06uplink \xcf\xfb\x84\x99\x9c/*\x10b827ebfffebce2d30\xbd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01=\x00\x00 AEf\x06YDH\x05P\x01Z\x01C`\x84\x0bh\x08z \x02\x05E!"\x00\x00\x11\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd5\x0e\x00\x82\x01"\n\x10b827ebfffebce2d3\x10\xbd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x1d\x00\x00 A'
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" - you have to show **what** does not work.

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: i can not convert the bytes stream i show in the question to json that related to my protobuf.

Comment: You may want to consider searching for ***protocol buffers python*** with the search site maintained by the same company where devs of protocol buffers work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Python tutorial on the Protobuf site:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial

The only practical way for you to use the protobuf byte stream messages that you've received is to use the protobuf tooling for -- in your case -- Python (since that's the language you're using and one of the many languages for which protobuf tooling is available).

You will need to compile the proto file that you referenced in your question into Python file(s). This tool is called [`protoc`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf).

You will then need to import the generated Python files into your code.

The generated files will provide functions to unmarshal on-the-wire byte streams into Python classes so that you may use them in your code.

If you read through the tutorial linked above, it should explain some of the details.